# Plotly sunburst graph not showing

Tags: python, plot, plotly, offline, sunburst-diagram

`Im currently doing a project,and created a sunburst graph using the following codes`

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig10=px.sunburst(df,path=["dep","edu","perfo"], color="perfo")
fig10.update_layout(title='Location and Sales_Agent',title_x=0.5)
fig10.update_traces(textinfo="label+percent parent")
```

When i try re-open the jupiter notebook, this graph is not showing??`

> any solution for this issue??`

Comment: Without data to reproduce the graph, it is impossible to comment.

Comment: we can't help you unless we know what `df` looks like. at a minimum please include a sample of your df. you can copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` directly into your question

Comment: found alternative..Thank u